# Obtaining the id of the user's session in firebase is not obtained?

Tags: android-studio, firebase-authentication

It is working in android studio and managing cell phone authentication in firebase,
Can't get user session id in firebase,
It works in a first activity but wanting to obtain a second activity is where the problem occurs, and the app closes automatically.
The code is in a provider class which is this:

```
public String getId(){
        if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            return auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

to get the id of the session in another class of an activity I instantiate the provider class and do this:

```
Provider provider = new Provider();
Log.d("id",provider.getId());
```

Someone who can tell me what may be happening, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare and initialize FirebaseAuth again in the activity where you want to fetch current user's userID.

Try like this:

```
    public String getId(){

       if( FirebaseAuth.getInstance() != null)
              return  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
       else
           return null;
       
     }
```

Comment: Excellent, it works, because the session id is not obtained when instantiating and calling the method in charge of said action in the Provider class to the activity class? Could you tell me :) please

Comment: you are making default object of Provider class so you should must have instantiate ```FirebaseAuth``` and the method in its constructor.

Comment: inside the constructor of the Provider class is:
 public Provider () {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance ();
 
    }
   then said method shown above.

Comment: just simply put method there.